# Recommened Image Size & Aspect Ratio

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection-api

What's the recommended image size (px) and aspect ratio when using tensorflow's object recognition API ?
Also, does it make sense to convert images to grayscale beforehand ?

Answer (score 0):

You need not convert the images to greyscale for tf object detection and the image size depends on the selected model, most of the SSD models have image size as 224 * 224.

Comment: Nope, not quite, after doing some searching, turns out it depends on what you want to detect. If you need color, use color images, if you need higher res, use higher res, but it will take longer for training.